# Encrypting file with checksum of the same file

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, aes, checksum

How safe is it to encrypt your files with a cipher like AES-256-CBC with the checksum of the same file, used as a key? Is that a risk, or is it safe?

Like this steps:

1. Generating the checksum of a file
2. Encrypting file with checksum of the file
3. Saving encrypted file on a server or disk
4. Encrypting checksum with a RSA/ECC Public key
5. Saving encrypted checksum on a server or disk

Decrypting:

1. Decrypting checksum with RSA/ECC Private key
2. Using checksum to decrypt file

Are my ideas safe?

Comment: why bother to calculate checksum instead of random key? I suspect in some cases, e.g. files with lot of zeros using checksum can lead to a predictable key

Comment: Well, I got a reason to do it. But I don't know if it's safe to do it..

Comment: This would be better asked on http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is known as "convergent encryption" and recently also as "message locked encryption". We have a related question on crypto.se: [Is Convergent Encryption really secure?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/729/is-convergent-encryption-really-secure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodesInChaos answered my question with a URL. I want to redirect you to:

- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/729/is-convergent-encryption-really-secure
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7142/online-backup-how-could-encryption-and-de-duplication-be-compatible

Comment: If you are happy with your answer please accept it (you should be able to do so now) so that people looking for unanswered questions won't find yours in their search results. Some feedback on your answer: It is better if you not only include a link but an actual answer, even though it might be short. See this question for more explanation: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 0):

for encripting an file to checksum is more or less easy; you can use the library like cripto-js

```
npm install cripto-js
```

And if you use typescript

```
npm install @types/criptojs
```

After that you already install this library, you must convert the file (image) to MD5 and then, convert the STRING generate for MD5 to base64.

You can run some this:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = (event: any) => {
    let binari = event.target.result;
    let md5 = criptoJS.MD5(binari).toString();
    const encodedWord = criptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(md5);
    const encoded = criptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encodedWord);
    resolve(reader.result);
  };
  reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
});
```

and yes, i am run typescript.

I hope this it work for you. :) happy coding